# URl Redirect using AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, redirect, dns, forwarding

a simple question with potentially no solution?

Ok, so I have 2 servers, 2 public IPs and one domain resolves to server1, let's say it's [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

That server1 is hosting services under:

- [www.example.com/apple](http://www.example.com/apple),
- [www.example.com/banana](http://www.example.com/banana),
- [www.example.com/cherry](http://www.example.com/cherry)

I need to set up `www.example.com/pear` to go to `server2` while keeping all others still pointing to `server1`.

Some details:

- those URLs are constructed programmatically. So the only option is to specify 'fruit', and the rest of the API calls are constructed without any flexibility.
- I do have control over example.com Route53 zone
- I have no control over the server1, which is hosting apple, banana, and cherry services

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a solution for your problem. You can use Appliation Load Balancers for path-based routing. Create a target groups for each servers. Direct /banana /apple and /cherry to target group server1, and /pear to target group server2.

Then point your Route 53 record to this load balancer.
Let me know for any further problems.

Related documents :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try, sounds pretty logical to me.
How would it behave if the calls are rtmp:// ?